# pivot in oracle with different column

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot

I have a query like below:

```
select  "customerNumber" as "customerNumber", "customerName",nvl("1",0) as "1",nvl("3",0) as "3",nvl("2",0) as "2",nvl("4",0) as "4" ,nvl("5",0) as "5" , "depId" 
 from (

SELECT /*+   PARALLEL(auto) */ CUSTOMER_NUMBER "customerNumber",
  BALANCE "balance" , "depId",
  CASE
    WHEN CUSTOMER_NUMBER < 0
    THEN ' حساب مشترک'
    ELSE cn.name
  END AS "customerName"
  ,MODALITY_TYPE
FROM
  ( select * from (SELECT /*+   PARALLEL(auto) */ CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
    SUM(BALANCE) AS BALANCE,
    max(ref_dep_id) "depId"
    ,MODALITY_TYPE
  FROM TBL_CONC_RPORT_DETAIL
  GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NUMBER,MODALITY_TYPE
  ORDER BY 2 DESC) where ROWNUM <101
  )tcrd
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
    /*+   PARALLEL(auto) */
    CUS_ID,
    NAME
    ||' '
    ||FAMILY AS name
  FROM tbl_customer
  ) cn
ON CN.CUS_ID = TCRD.CUSTOMER_NUMBER

ORDER BY 2 DESC 
  )
            PIVOT
            (max("balance") FOR MODALITY_TYPE IN (1 as "1",2 as "2",3 as "3",4 as "4",5 as "5"))
            ORDER BY nvl("1",0)+nvl("2",0)+nvl("3",0)+nvl("4",0)+nvl("5",0) DESC;
```

the result is :
[image]

problem:
in some rows I have different "dep_id" so pivot does not work like selected area in below picture:

[image]

I want to to combine this two rows like below (and have one of the "dep_id" randomly)

[image]

P.S: I dont want to join or write another select for "dep_id" because I have lots of rows  and it take so many times.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
  max(ref_dep_id) "depId"
```

you should write

```
   first_value("dep_id") over (partition by "customerNumber")
```